# Unrecognized options "args" under "finite_finite.sylius_order.callbacks.after.sylius_complete"

Tags: configuration, config, sylius

I pulled the latest sylius code yesterday/a couple days ago (the whole standard bundle) to get fixes. I'm getting the error I put as the title of this question. I looked at the finite.yml file in the SyliusOrderBundle to make sure it was exactly the same as the [finite.yml](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusOrderBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/finite.yml) on github. Since I pulled everything, I should've also pulled whatever was necessary to make this change of setting callbacks in the config work. I've been googling but haven't found anyone else who observed this problem. I tried undoing whatever I thought would've affected this (e.g. uncommented my override of the order repository)and did another composer.phar update so that I had the latest of all the other bundles, but nothing's worked so far. Does anyone have any insight to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my composer.json wasn't properly merged with Sylius's updated one. After doing a correct merge, I was able to continue working out the kinks in my app.